# Hbase put with timestamp fails when trying to update column value

Tags: java, hbase

I'm creating a row in hbase using a put as follows:

```
Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));
put.add(Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily), Bytes.toBytes(qualifier), cellTimestamp, value);
```

These puts get batched and then added to hbase as:

```
table.setAutoFlushTo(true);
table.put(batch);
table.flushCommits();
```

This works for new rows.  If I then try and update the column value and specify a new cellTimestamp, the data does not get updated. Is this possible? The hbase table is created with  VERSIONS => '1'.

Thanks in advnace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally discouraged to provide the cellTimestamp, but in case you need it please make sure that cellTimestamp...

- ... is greater than the one of the previous version
- ... it's in milliseconds

Here are some nice readings about versioning & how HBase handles timestamps:

- http://hbase.apache.org/book/versions.html
- http://www.ngdata.com/bending-time-in-hbase

Comment: Thank you Ruben, that makes sense and helped me solved my issue.  I'm going to leave the timestamp alone for that cell, but if I add a timestamp that is > the current timestamp, it works!  Many thanks.